# Kotlin: parameter of inline function with generics are not found at runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, inline, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

Firstly, I'm a newbie in the Kotlin programming language. So keywords and concepts like `inline`, `reified` and `crossinline` are not clear enough in my head, yet. In the sample code below, I'm using these keywords because I need to know the type of `T` at runtime to serialize and deserialize it before and after to make web requests.

This is the `post` function of `ApiClient` class:

```
inline fun <reified T> post(entity: T, crossinline completion : (entity : T?, errorStatusCode: Int?) -> Unit) {
    performRequest(
        httpMethod = Request.Method.POST,
        entity =  entity,
        completion =  completion)
}
```

Then, I call this function from `PassengerRepositoryImpl`:

```
override fun register(passenger: Passenger, completion: (passenger: Passenger?, errorStatusCode: Int?) -> Unit) {

    apiClient.post(passenger, completion)
}
```

My problem is that my `entity` and `completion` parameters are always "not found" inside the post function, as you can see in the following images:

`passenger` is correctly passed to `post` function:

[image: <code>passenger</code> is correctly passed to <code>post</code> function]

But `entity` parameter is not found insude `post` body.

[image: Cannot find find local variable <code>entity</code>]

My question is: how to solve this issue? Am I making any confusion?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are they not shown only in the debugger? did you try to log them?

Comment: I wonder if because you have reused the exact names in the lambdas that you are experiencing a shadowing issue. Try changing your entity parameter to body, and completion to callback, that might be all that is wrong, because this looks very similar to my implementation

Comment: Thanks Ogbe and Benjamin for the help. When I log the entity, it is logged right. Changing the parameter name did not work. But, I found an implementation error in my ´performRequest´ function. Fixing this bug the entity is correctly serialized / deserialized... I thinks it is some type of IDE bug or similar... The entity variable is correctly serialied and deserialized, but is not possbible to evaluate it at runtime. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you share the preformRequest? I might be able to help in that case.

Comment: @BenjaminCharais sure: [here](https://gist.github.com/peresbruno/3abf1e63907c66898edaf8e220f19081)